# echoing image from database is showing bunch of characters

Tags: php, image

image from database is put in an array then saved in $_SESSION header to new page but when echoed out its showing bunch of characters lines and lines of it...

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $queryArray[] = $row;
    } 
}
else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = true;
    $error = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;    
}

if($goodQuery){


    $_SESSION['search_output'] = $queryArray;
    header("Location: searchpage.php");

    exit;
}
```

then...

```
<?php

        if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){          
            echo $_SESSION['error'];                                    
        } else { 

            echo ($_SESSION['count']);
              foreach($_SESSION['search_output'] as $value){
                $value['id'];  
                $value['links'];
                $value['title'];
                $value['page_body'];
                $value['thumbs'];

                $id = $value['id'];
                $title = $value['title'];
                $link = $value['links'];
                $body = $value['page_body'];
                $thumbs = $value['thumbs'];

                $search_output .= "<a href='".$link."'>".$title."</a> - $body<br>";}
}
?>

    <?php echo $search_output; ?><?php echo $thumbs; ?>
```

how can i fix this. basically i want a thumbnail to show up beside each search result.

Comment: Variable $links contains only links to the actual pages.. there are no image links just images which are stored in 'thumbs'.

Comment: not quite sure what you are asking.. but only one link one image one title and one body for each search result

Comment: Do you store your images as strings in DB or you store them as files?

Comment: the column type would be blob so is that a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upon further research since it was saved as an image stored in a mysql blob... convert the image data into base64 and stick it in an  tagimage data into base64 and stick it in an  tag.*(not my words)*

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $thumbs ) . '" />';
```

this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a problem with encoding when links stored in data base , make sure the encoding between db and pages works well.
for example by using `mysql_set_charset('utf8')`

:)

Comment: isnt it  mysql_set_charset('utf8') by default?